# Trace norm is invariant under conjugation by an isometry

Tags: linear-algebra, isometry

How would I go about showing that for the trace norm of a matrix, given by $||M||_1=Tr(\sqrt{M^{\dagger}M})$, is invariant under conjugation by an isometry? That is, $||UMU^{\dagger}||_1=||M||_1$. The text I am reading says this is the case because the eigenvalues of the two are the same, but I fail to see even why this is the case. For an isometry I know we have that $U^{\dagger}U=I$, but I don't know how to proceed. (If it helps, the book is discussing Hermitian matrices.

Comment: Do you see why, if $A$ is positive-definite, $\sqrt{UAU^H} = U\sqrt{A}U^H$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can start with 
\begin{align}
\|UMU^T\|_1 &= Tr\sqrt{\Big((UMU^T)^T(UMU^T)\Big)} \\
& = Tr\sqrt{\Big(UM^TU^TUMU^T\Big)}\\
&= Tr\sqrt{\Big(UM^TMU^T\Big)}\\
\end{align}

Now, we want to use the following facts. First, $Tr AB = Tr BA$ for any matrices $A$ and $B$. But we have a nasty square root in the way. So let's fix that. We know that $M^TM$ is positive semi-definite. So
$$
M^TM = SDS^{-1}
$$ 
for some invertible $S$ and diagonal positive $D$. So we can compute

$$
(US\sqrt{D}S^{-1}U^T)^2 = (US\sqrt{D}S^{-1}U^T)(US\sqrt{D}S^{-1}U^T)=US\sqrt{D}\sqrt{D}S^{-1}U^T=UM^TMU^T
$$
So we can finish with
\begin{align}
Tr\sqrt{\Big(UM^TMU^T\Big)} &= Tr\Big(U\sqrt{M^TM}U^T\Big)\\
&=Tr\Big(U^TU\sqrt{M^TM}\Big)
\end{align}